React-Beautiful-DND - I Have treenode while dragging child node below parent also overlapping. I need to move within the hierarchy level
React-Beautiful-DND - Treenode while dragging child node below parent also overlapping. I need to move within the hierarchy level.
I need only child node to move overlap the parent node.
enter image description here
While Dragging child node 34 parent node 33 also moving and overlapping. How to fix this issue
